# Loop Through well Nested JSON

Tags: php, jquery, html, json

I have JSON:

```
{
    "PaperName": "Mathematics",
    "Instruction": null,
    "MaxTime": "2 hr",
    "Maxmarks": 100,
    "Question": [
        {
            "Type": "Objective",
            "QuesDetails": " Terms in an expression which have the same literal factors are called",
            "Marks": 1,
            "Order": 2,
            "Description": "This is the question Descripttion",
            "view": "View Answer",
            "Answer": [
                {
                    "Ans": "(A) Bhagat Singh"
                },
                {
                    "Ans": "(B) B.R.Ambedkar"
                },
                {
                    "Ans": "(C) J.L.Nehru"
                },
                {
                    "Ans": "(D) L.K.Advani."
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Type": "Objective",
            "QuesDetails": "An algebraic expression of two terms is known as",
            "Marks": 1,
            "Order": 2,
            "Description": "This is the question Descripttion",
            "view": "View Answer",
            "Answer": [
                {
                    "Ans": "(A) Bhagat Singh"
                },
                {
                    "Ans": "(B) B.R.Ambedkar"
                },
                {
                    "Ans": "(C) J.L.Nehru"
                },
                {
                    "Ans": "(D) L.K.Advani."
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Type": "Objective",
            "QuesDetails": "An algebraic expression of three terms is known as",
            "Marks": 1,
            "Order": 2,
            "Description": "This is the question Descripttion",
            "view": "View Answer",
            "Answer": [
                {
                    "Ans": "(A) Bhagat Singh"
                },
                {
                    "Ans": "(B) B.R.Ambedkar"
                },
                {
                    "Ans": "(C) J.L.Nehru"
                },
                {
                    "Ans": "(D) L.K.Advani."
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I want to convert this into HTML.

I tried via below code:

```
var str="";
for(var item in json.Question){
str += "<tr>";
for(idata in json.Question[item]){
       str += '<td>'+json.Question[item][idata]+'</td>';

    }
  str+="</tr>";
 }
 $('#result').html("<table><th>Type</th><th>Ques Detail</th><th>Marks</th>
 <th>Order</th><th>Description</th><th></th><th>Answer</th>"+str+"</table>");
```

Bur for answer `key` I am getting output as `[Object][Object]`. Please let me know how to access that and display in HTML.

Comment: Well, first you'd pick a programming language/execution environment to use.

Comment: i am using PHP and HTML with jQuery

Comment: You have an XSS vulnerability.

Comment: Then why not  tag your question appropriately?

Comment: Could you please paste the JSON into the question? There's no reason to have it as a downloadable file. If it's too big trim it down to a reasonable size.

Comment: @Juhana .. pasted JSON

Comment: @SLaks Can you elaborate? It would probably be more helpful to OP and other users to know what the vulnerability is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
json.Question.forEach(function(objective){
    console.log(objective);
    objective.Answer.forEach(function(answer){
        console.log(answer.Ans);
    });
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/newblt123/aWpgC/)

Let me know if this helps.

**Edit: Print some html.**

```
$("#myTable")
    .append("<tr><td>PaperName: " + json.PaperName + "</td></tr>")
    .append("<tr><td>Instructions: " + json.Instructions + "</td></tr>")
    .append("<tr><td>MaxTime: " + json.MaxTime + "</td></tr>")
    .append("<tr><td>Maxmarks: " + json.Maxmarks + "</td></tr>");
json.Question.forEach(function(objective){
    $("#myTable").append("<tr><td>Objective type: " + objective.Type + "</td></tr>");
    // etc
    objective.Answer.forEach(function(answer){
        $("#myTable").append("<tr><td>Answer: " + answer.Ans + "</td></tr>");
    });
});
```

[**Updated demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/newblt123/aWpgC/5/)

Comment: please help to print as HTML

Comment: Edited my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

run `json_decode` on your json and then:

```
$j = json_decode($json);

foreach($j->Question as $q)
{
    echo $q->QuesDetails;
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($q->Answer as $ans)
    {
        echo '<li>' . $ans->Ans . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

***[Demo](http://ideone.com/Q5NaAf)***

Answer (score 0):

The answers array is an array of objects.
So

```
Json = {
Question = "Question"
Item = "Answer"
idata = "Ans": "(A) Bhagat Singh"
idata.ans = "(A) Bhagat Singh"
```

So you either need one more for loop or you need to change the array to be an array of strings
example

"Answer": [
"(A) Bhagat Singh",
    "(B) B.R.Ambedkar",
    "(C) J.L.Nehru",
    "(D) L.K.Advani."
    ]